# Could not initialize class error in Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

I keep getting this error even though I already changed the `HibernateUtil.java` file:

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class itd.pabwe.contactbook.entities.HibernateUtil

How to solve this error?

Here is my HibernatUtil.java code.

```
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistryBuilder;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;
import org.hibernate.service.ServiceRegistry;

public class HibernateUtil {

private static SessionFactory sessionFactory;

/*
static {
    try {
        // Create the SessionFactory from standard (hibernate.cfg.xml) 
        // config file.
        factory = new AnnotationConfiguration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
        Configuration configuration = new Configuration().configure();
        StandardServiceRegistryBuilder builder = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(configuration.getProperties());
        SessionFactory factory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(builder.build());

    } catch (Throwable ex) {
        // Log the exception. 
        System.err.println("Initial SessionFactory creation failed." + ex);
        throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
    }
}
*/
public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
    if(sessionFactory==null){
        //loads configuration and mappings
        Configuration configuration = new Configuration().configure();
        ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(configuration.getProperties()).build();

        //build a session factory from the service registry
        sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);
    }

    return sessionFactory;

}
}
```

Here I'm using **Hibernate 4.3.x**. Please help me

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there seems to be build issue in your workspace.Please see your jdk and jre is configured correctly.

Comment: You might have to check if this class file is getting generated in your respective target folders to confirm if your code is compiled and interpreted.